# Retrieving erring procedure name , error state , severity and line number in HANA

Tags: sql, stored-procedures, hana, hana-sql-script

I have a stored procedure written in T-SQL. I am trying to write equivalent procedure in HANA. I am facing some roadblocks, which are :

- I am not able to find equivalent of ERROR_STATE(), ERROR_SEVERITY(), ERROR_PROCEDURE(), ERROR_LINE() functions in HANA. They are part of Transact SQL native error handling functions. I am aware of existence of ::SQL_ERROR_CODE and ::SQL_ERROR_MESSAGE. What are the corresponding system views/tables where they are defined.
- Equivalent of RETURN  statement in HANA, which we can give before a CATCH block ends in T-SQL.
- Equivalent of BEGIN TRAN in HANA.
  TIA

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sqlscript does currently not provide a corresponding access to the error location.